# How to disable Clover2 on Maven 3 project?

Tags: java, maven, clover

I have **Java** project, use **Maven 3.0.5** for building. **Clover2** is configured in parent pom. But I want to disable Clover in my project. I used command `-DenableClover=false` with Maven 2 and it works, but it does not work with Maven 3, Clover is not disabled.

Also I tried `-Dmaven.clover.skip=true` command, but it does not help too.

I use **maven-clover2-plugin:2.6.3**.

How I can disbale Clover2 on Maven 3 project?

Answer (score 0):

`-Dmaven.clover.skip=true` is a [proper way](https://docs.atlassian.com/maven-clover2-plugin/2.6.3/setup-mojo.html#skip) to disable Clover. Please make sure the property is properly propagated to Clover. It may be *lost* by various reasons, e.g. JVM/lifecycle forking.